# Integrating $I=\int_0^1 \ln x \space\cdot\ln(1-x)\space dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, logarithms

While I was practicing calculus today ,I was held up by this guy.

$$I=\int_0^1 \ln x \space\cdot\ln(1-x)\space dx$$
I have no idea where to start , I think $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\space \sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{r^2}\space= \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
might be helpful .
Any suggestion are appreciated . Cheers!

Comment: Is this an indefinite integral? Or do you have some bounds for integration?

Comment: I've edited the question,Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: No problem!!!!!

Comment: Yes mate, That was quite quick

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral_0%5E1+ln%28x%29*ln%281-x%29+dx) this thing doesn't look pretty and [$\operatorname{Li}_2(x)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html) shows up.

Comment: @Alexey Burdin indeed it won't be pretty to integrate indefinitely, but from 0 to 1 the answer is doable (using Taylor Series)